# "Vue warn: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined" only on components from files

Tags: php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I have yet to get any Vue components working in my application. The error above is the only indication I get as to what is wrong. So far, all attempts at finding a resolution through research on SO and other sites have failed.

If I explicitly declare like so, it works as expected:

```
Vue.component('sidebar-entry', {
    data: function () {
        return {
            route: '',
            icon_slug: ''
        }
    },
    template: '<li class="nav-item"><slot></slot></li>'
});
```

But if I `import` or `require` the component from a `.vue` file, the component appears to load but I get the aforementioned error.

In my webpack.config.js, I have an alias for 'vue$' to 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'. I also have a vue-loader for .vue files.

Comment: How are you loading single file vue components?

Comment: Please provide a non-working example so we can see what you may possible be doing wrong.